# How to change X-axis interval in chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, chart.js

Now i am working with "chart.js", I receive dynamic monthly report data from server. There is a 31 data in x-axis, i want to display the x-axis value into multiple of 5 (5,10,15,20,25,30).

We can do this, but only as a static value, by following method.

```
var thisYearData = {
  labels: ["Jul 5", "Jul 10", "Jul 15", "Jul 20", "Jul 25", "Jul 30"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "This year dataset",
    fillColor: "#9C2E9D",
    strokeColor: "#9C2E9D",
    pointColor: "transparent",
    pointStrokeColor: "transparent",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "#9C2E9D",
    data: [45, 62, 15, 78, 58, 98]
  }]
};
```

But i would like to provide a interval dynamically.

We can able to provide interval to Y-axis By following method.

```
var lastYearChart = new Chart(lastYearCTX).LineAlt2(lastYearData, {
  datasetFill: false,
  scaleSteps: 5,
  scaleStepWidth: 20,
  scaleStartValue: 0
});
```

But scaleSteps: 5, scaleStepWidth: 20, i need these options for X-axis.

As you can see the current output from following screenshot.

[image]

My Script:

```
var flwrgrwth = document.getElementById("followergrowth").getContext("2d");
    Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt2",
    initialize: function() {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        var originalStroke = ctx.stroke;
        ctx.stroke = function() {
            ctx.save();
            originalStroke.apply(this, arguments)
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
});

var flwrgrwthchart = {
    labels: data.ltxt_array,
    datasets: [{
        label: "Twitter Follower Growth",
        fillColor: "#54c0eb",
        strokeColor: "#54c0eb",
        pointColor: "transparent",
        pointStrokeColor: "transparent",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "#54c0eb",
        data: data.lval_array,
    }]
};

var twitflwrgrwthscale = new Chart(flwrgrwth).LineAlt2(flwrgrwthchart, {
    datasetFill: false,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
    scaleFontSize: 10,
    scaleFontColor: '#111111',
    scaleGridLineColor: '#f5f5f5',
    scaleLineColor: '#f5f5f5',
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 5,
    scaleStepWidth: 20,
    scaleStartValue: 0
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You are using data string as the label so any built-in logic is not going to work.

You can create labels dynamically based on the selected date range and interval.

```
var labels = [];
// get interval
var interval  = 5;
//Get start date
var date_start =  new Date("July 5");
for ( var i = 0; i <= 30; i += interval) {
    //Set date
    date_start.setDate(date_start.getDate() + interval);
    //get Month
    var month_name  = date_start.toLocaleString(navigator.language, { month: "short" });
    //Add to labels
    labels.push(month_name + " " + date_start.getDate());
}
```

Comment: It's Working.. Thank you.. :)